# Remove/stop 'redactor-inline-converted'

Tags: redactor, richtext

Not specifically a Craft problem but I'm struggling to find an answer from Redactors site.

I've got over 100 occurrences of class="redactor-inline-converted" littered throughout the markup of Rich Text fields. How can I stop Redactor adding this class?

---

Update 2016-04-26

Here's the steps to recreate this. It's an odd thing between Redactor and Word.

1. Have styled text in Word with a superscript
2. Copy / paste in to Craft
3. Add some text and format it
4. Check the source and Redactor will add `class="redactor-inline-converted"`

This happens randomly on all tags:

```
<strong class="redactor-inline-converted"><em class="redactor-inline-converted">Superscript</em></strong>
<ul><li><em class="redactor-inline-converted">list item</em></li></ul>
```

Video example:
http://sendvid.com/h41rosb3

Comment: What version of Craft/Redactor?  Any idea on how they get inserted?

Comment: Craft CMS 2.6.2780 and whatever version of Redactor comes with Craft. The text is being copied from Word on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but I strip it out as part of a cleanup macro that runs on body text.

```
{% macro cleanup(string) -%}
    {%- if string|length -%}
        {{- string|typogrify|replace('<p><br></p>','')|replace('redactor-inline-converted','')|raw -}}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro %}
```

Comment: Thanks @maxfenton I've done the same with a bit of regex but it would be good to have clean data stored as I never want these classes.